# Hadoop Production Infrastructure - Storage Dilema

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, storage, nfs

Few Months back i managed to setup a very Basic Hadoop Cluster with just using 3 Virtual Machine 2 as Namenode (Active & Standby) and 1 as DataNode. I even installed Zookeeper to enable HA for Namenode. Also i was using Namenode as Datanode (I know this is BIG NO in production environment) , I did just for testing. The installation i did was basically by downloading the Hadoop and other binaries and not by using any CDH installation , Just to learn on underlying config files and how does it affect the setup.

The Storage space of these three VM's were mapped to an Dedicated Volume share from NFS (We have NFS infrastructure already been setup and in use).

Now after playing around with all the setup & installation , we have decided to Move fwd and setup an Production environment. At first this will be very basic cluster with maximum 4-5 Datanodes. I plan to purchase Two high end servers to Act as Namenode & Standby Namenode. Whereas for Datanode , i am confused.

We will not be making use of MapReduce framework and planned to work with Apache Spark. So our jobs will be Memory intensive as Spark being used. So my basic understanding would be , The Memory (RAM) of these Datanode should be on higher end to run Spark Worker daemon. And how about the Storage for Datanode ? Is it Mandatory to use the Local Hard disk space for store data in Datanode ? Or can i Map the storage to an NFS Volume just like i did for testing environment.

Can someone tell me the Pros and Cons of setting up storage on Datanode via NFS and not physical local storage - specially when i plan to run Spark Jobs. Does this affect the processing speed ?

Also , the NFS Infrastructure is setup with RAID capability. So in that case should i even bother to set the replication factor in Hadoop  - If i end up using NFS for storage purpose.

Sorry for these questions , Hope someone can clear this ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

Local Storage (or DAS - Direct Attached Storage) gives better IOPS (ok, i know arguably and hadoop is born on the premise of commodity hardware with compute, memory and storage local to each node), compared to using centralized storage (like SAN, NAS).

So i would say if you are ok with the IOPS you get from NFS sure but remember you have to present it as HDFS. If you have RAID that meets your requirements you can go with 1 as replication factor and save on storage costs.

If you are not going to use MapReduce and use NFS as storage and interested in Spark you don't need Hadoop/HDFS you can install Spark directly on bare metal (or VM's) without Hadoop and do everything you want.